# pushing notification to Google Home speakers

Tags: google-home, google-assist-api

I am looking for a way to push a notification to Google Home speakers by an ESP32 (running on the same network).

Is there any c++ library to do so?

I previously used [this](https://github.com/horihiro/esp8266-google-home-notifier) but it seems it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

[Proactive notifications](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/notifications) can be pushed to speakers for supported Smart Home traits.